# I am getting following error "Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code."

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Chrome version :79.0.3945.79

Chrome Webdriver :Chrome WebDriver 79

Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Dec 13, 2019 3:06:44 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

Comment: Upgrading to ChromeDriver 79 still showing same error